# Use js file as cdn in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I made a library in jquery an hosted in to my shared hosting. That js file is accessible when I hit from browser . But if I set it in my html like cdn it's not working. That's mean if I use code directly without use separate file it works but when I keep that js code in a file and include file then not works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
body code ...........

 <script src="https://mydomain/acdn/jsfile.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

My cdn file

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('get-list') }}',
            .........................
     })
 </script>
```

**here shows error Unexpected identifier in {{ url('get-list') }}**

Comment: script tag is not required while loading javascript from file. You can remove <script> & </script> from your js file.

Comment: I also tried with that. but not works

Comment: ["then not works"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not a useful description of the problem. Do some debugging. Look at the developer tools in the browser. Look at the Console: Are any error reported there? Look at the Network tab: Is the request for the JS file made? Does it have the expected response? Is the status code correct? Is the Content-Type correct? Is the body of the response the script you expect?

Comment: Are you sure your JS-file is loaded? Please look into your network diagnostics in developer tools if the file is loaded.

Comment: Also, can you add type="text/javascript" along with src attribute

Comment: @ rojadesign . Yes . Its loaded . I checked from console

Comment: @Yoganand . Yes . still not works

Comment: Can you make a working demo?

Comment: @Yoganand — No! The only purpose of a `type` attribute for loading a traditional JS file is to break everything when the author makes a typo.

Comment: @Quentin noted.

Comment: I updated my post . Please have a look  **here shows error Unexpected identifier in {{ url('get-list') }}**

Comment: And what is `{{ url('get-list') }}` supposed to _be_ …? Looks like some kind of server-side templating language? In that case, it of course won’t work, if you don’t make the script file get run through whatever processor that requires in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JavaScript contains:

> ```
> '{{ url('get-list') }}'
> ```

This appears to be some kind of template code that the server-side code which generates your HTML document will replace with some data.

When you take it out of the HTML document, it is no longer being generated by that server-side code so won't be replaced. The JS parser therefore attempts to parse it, fails, and throws an error.

Move the template code back inside your HTML, then read the data from the HTML document using the JS.

e.g.

```
<script src="..." data-url="{{ url('get-list') }}">
```

And then in your script:

```
const url = document.currentScript.dataset.url;
```

(Make sure you change any logic which escapes the data to make it safe to be injected into JS to logic which makes it safe to be injected in HTML).

Comment: @Mithun — That is a consequence of not following the advice in [ask]. It took people quarter of an hour of commenting before you put enough information in the question to identify the problem. Downvotes are there to warn people that a question is low quality and not worth their time, and that is the state your question was in.